# Why is Atom only allowing me to use the standard python library

Tags: python, python-import, atom-editor

I have recently changed my text editor from IDLE to Atom but when I started to run my program that i have ran in the past eg(music player using pygame) it didn't work and came up with this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jacquelinethompson/Desktop/Untitled.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
[Finished in 0.088s]
```

I checked the import to see if it worked in IDLE and it works fine there. Can anyone explain why and how to fix it.

I am on the MacOS and am using python3.6

Comment: How did you set up Atom to run Python programs? Do you know if it is using a virtual environment? Most likely IDLE and Atom are looking in different places for installed packages.

Comment: Do you use the `script` module to start python? It tries to use python2 by default if it is installed (you can check what it used with `import sys;print(sys.version); print(sys.executable)`), in the Page for `script` is a description how to set it to python3